# How to copy Cells from one excel file to another in MATLAB

Tags: excel-formula, matlab

I am a beginner in MATLAB .I have one excel sheet like this

```
excelsheet1.xlsx = 
  Name     Age
  Tom      20
  Dick     15
  Harry    25
```

Now i want to copy the column A from excelsheet1.xlsx and make another excel file like this

```
excelsheet2.xlsx =
  Name   Age_after_5_years
  Tom       25 
  dick      20
  Harry     30
```

Please help me . Thanks in advance

Comment: Aren't Name and Age on two different columns?

Comment: @Divakar , yes they are 2 different columns. please help me out

Comment: See if the posted solution works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `Name` and `Age` were on two different columns - `A` and `B`, see if this works for you -

```
[~,~,raw] = xlsread('excelsheet1.xlsx')
raw{1,2} = 'Age_after_5_years'
raw(2:end,2) = num2cell(cell2mat(raw(2:end,2))+5)
xlswrite('excelsheet2.xlsx',raw(:,1:2))
```

Comment: A small addition: If you want to repeatedly write to the same excel file `xlswrite` can be very slow. This [`improved xlswrite`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27236-improved-xlswrite-m) makes it much faster.

Comment: @Divakar ; Thanks a lot Sir ,
 But my actual objective was to just copy the Column A from excelsheet1.xlsx into Column A of excelsheet2.xlsx . I have my differnt logic and formulae to assign the data in Column B of excelsheet2.xlsx . Can you suggest me something else for that . Anyway thanks a lot

Comment: @Arpi Awesome! Thank you! That's a good pointer for OP to take advantage of, is performance is a criteria!

Comment: @pradeepkumarTarei Consider accepting this solution by clicking on the hollow checkmark next to it, if this has solved your question.